# Integrate a complex function with scipy.integrate

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, floating-point, complex-numbers

I want to integrate a function numerically. In this function I have two types of spherical coordinates (r,th) and (rp,thp). I want to integrate on (rp,thp) and I try to give values to (r,th) using if loop.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

wavelength = 1e-3  # m
R = 5  # m radius
aperture_diameter = 5e-1  # m
k = 2 * np.pi / wavelength  # the wavenumber

# Define the number of points in the ring
num_points = 100
r_values = np.linspace(0, aperture_diameter / 2, num_points)
th_values = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, num_points)

def f(rp, thp):
    integrand = np.zeros_like(rp)
    for i, rp_val in enumerate(rp):
        for j, th_val in enumerate(thp):
            integrand[i] = rp_val * np.exp(-1j * k / (2 * R) * (r_values[i]**2 + rp_val**2 - 2 * r_values[i]**2 * rp_val**2 * (np.cos(th_values[j]) * np.cos(th_val) + np.sin(th_values[j]) * np.sin(th_val))))
    return integrand

# Define the integration limits
rp_limits = [0, int(aperture_diameter / 2)]
thp_limits = [0, int(2 * np.pi)]

# Perform numerical integration
result, _ = quad(lambda rp, thp: f(rp, thp), *rp_limits, *thp_limits)

print(result)
```

But I got the error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Please help me I am confused.

Comment: Please provide the complete traceback

Comment: `scipy.integrate.quad` is for a single-variable integral. For a double integral, you should use `scipy.integrate.dblquad`. The python function you integrate should take in a single input point (`x` and `y` for `dblquad`, or just `x` for `quad`) and return a single value. What's the mathematical function you're trying to evaluate, and how does it depend on `r`, `th`, `rp`, and `thp`?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "if loop".

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually read, and try to understand, the error?  Or just run  to us begging for help?

Here's the full error message:

```
In [44]: result, _ = quad(lambda rp, thp: f(rp, thp), *rp_limits, *thp_limits)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 1
----> 1 result, _ = quad(lambda rp, thp: f(rp, thp), *rp_limits, *thp_limits)

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:411, in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    408 flip, a, b = b < a, min(a, b), max(a, b)
    410 if weight is None:
--> 411     retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
    412                    points)
    413 else:
    414     if points is not None:

File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_quadpack_py.py:523, in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    521 if points is None:
    522     if infbounds == 0:
--> 523         return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    524     else:
    525         return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

Cell In[44], line 1, in <lambda>(rp, thp)
----> 1 result, _ = quad(lambda rp, thp: f(rp, thp), *rp_limits, *thp_limits)

Cell In[43], line 15, in f(rp, thp)
     13 def f(rp, thp):
     14     integrand = np.zeros_like(rp)
---> 15     for i, rp_val in enumerate(rp):
     16         for j, th_val in enumerate(thp):
     17             integrand[i] = rp_val * np.exp(-1j * k / (2 * R) * (r_values[i]**2 + rp_val**2 - 2 * r_values[i]**2 * rp_val**2 * (np.cos(th_values[j]) * np.cos(th_val) + np.sin(th_values[j]) * np.sin(th_val))))

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

So it's the `enumerate(rp)` that's giving problems.  `rp` as passed to `f` by `quad` is a single float.  What were you expecting?

Earlier in the traceback

```
quad(func, a, b, args,...
```

So `func` is your `f` (the lambda doesn't change anything).  `a` and `b` come from your `*rp_limits`.  The `*thp_limits` is received as the `args` (or maybe just `thp_limits[0]`).

In any case you appear to written `f` and the limits as though you expected to do a 2 variable integration.  As the `quad` signature (and rest of its docs) should make clear, `quad` integrates JUST ONE variable.

When working with `quad` - or other `scipy` functions like this - make sure your inputs match the documented specifications.  They should clearly tell you what it requires of your `func` - in terms of arguments, and the various other parameters.  `quad` has full control; you have to conform to its behavior.